# Backing all the up to the root folder without multiple ../../

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, relative-path

Is there an alternative to having to do something like this:

```
"../../../../index.html"
```

when using relative links? According to an article I found on google you can use a `/` at the start of the link to back all the way up to the root folder, but when I've tried this it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific. Where do you try to use it? What is your structure?

Comment: `/` indeed does take you all the way back to the root *domain*.... do you have an example you can post where it did not work?

Comment: When using relative links that's the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a slash you go to the root.

In Unix you will go to the root of the drive, but when using it on the web it goes to the Document root.

ANything outside of the document root cannot be accessed by plain HTML.

Comment: Just for the record "\" = back slash, "/" = forward slash.

Comment: Ah yes, silly me I don't know why I thought it would automatically know where the root was on my desktop. I just tried it on my server and it worked fine, thanks.